# Проверить текстовое поле на первый символ

Tags: javascript, html

Есть текстовое поле, в которое нужно ввести значение из 9 символов, и нужно выдавать сообщение и делать кнопку не активной если первый символ в текстовом поле равняется 5, я понимаю что нужно использовать js, но не знаю как правильно это сделать, подскажите как это можно сделать.

```html
<form name ="formValid" action="xlsSpW09D02" >             
  <label>ПКВ</label>
  <input type="text" name="osdch" required pattern="[0-9]{9}" maxlength="9" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Код має містити 9 цифр!')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" id="osdch">
  <button  class="btnCollor btn  btn-md btn-success" 
           data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Сформувати xls-файл">Жмакай</button></div>       
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input[name='osdch']");
const button = document.querySelector("button.btn-success");

input.addEventListener("input", function() {
  if (+input.value.charAt(0) === 5) {
    console.log("Нельзя");
    button.setAttribute("disabled", true);
  } else {
    console.log("Можно");
    button.removeAttribute("disabled");
  }
});
```

```html
<form name="formValid" action="xlsSpW09D02">
  <label>ПКВ</label>
  <input type="text" name="osdch" required pattern="[0-9]{9}" maxlength="9" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Код має містити 9 цифр!')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" id="osdch">
  <button class="btnCollor btn  btn-md btn-success" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Сформувати xls-файл">Жмакай</button></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо большее, очень полезно! А не подскажете зачем вот здесь `+input.value` плюс перед `input`?

Comment: Вы молучаете значение `value` как строку, `+` делает из строки тип `number`